# Where does Mozilla Developer Network's Demo Studio save user's data?

Tags: firefox

I just accessed to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/the-planetarium/launch

Then I clicked on button "Like It" in the top bar. It showed "You Like". Then I cleared my Chrome's user data. But I still can see the button shows "You Like".

If I open this page on another browser, it shows "Like It".

So where does Mozilla Developer Network's Demo Studio save user's data? How can users delete their data? I think it's almost impossible for users to delete these data.

Comment: I guess you are having multiple profiles or you have not cleared your Google Chrome cache properly, I am getting no such issues. Try Ccleaner to clear Google Chrome cache in case you are still getting the issue.

Comment: If you try it in a Chrome's incognito window, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking this - the data isn't stored in the browser at all. It seems that the server remembers your choice using the combination of your IP address and user agent string. If I fire up a different browser I don't see my choice remembered. As soon as I manipulate the user agent string to be identical to the first browser I see "You Like" there. In other words, to "delete" your data you merely need to update your browser to a newer version (using some extension manipulating the user agent string will have the same effect) or reconnect to the Internet to get a new IP address.

**Update**: The source code of this app is apparently in Mozila's [kuma repository](https://github.com/mozilla/kuma/). The "like counter" is an `ActionCounterField` and the code managing uniqueness is [`ActionCounterUniqueManager`](https://github.com/mozilla/kuma/blob/7eba73f58d/apps/actioncounters/models.py#L36). If you check the [`get_unique` implementation](https://github.com/mozilla/kuma/blob/7eba73f58d/apps/actioncounters/utils.py#L43) you will see that it indeed uses the IP address and user agent to build a "user identifier" for non-authenticated users. The fact that changing the IP address seems to have no effect is probably a bug (might be related to Mozilla's reverse proxy responsible for caching).

**Update2**: Confirmed that this is a bug. I started Chrome and immediately saw that I like this demo - apparently the code currently sees the same IP address for everybody. Filed [bug 766492](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766492) on that.

Comment: Generally they store you data online ones you login to their system, I am doubtful of whether they track via IP Address or something, generally these are done via client side browser cookies.

Comment: Wladimir, thank you for your answer! As what you said, Mozilla may remember user agent string on their servers. And I just changed my IP address and I found the button still displays "You Like". So besides user agent string, another factor which they use appears not IP address. What's the another factor you think?

Comment: @WeiLou: Yes, a simple reconnect won't do, not quite sure what they do there. Still, they definitely don't store the data locally given that an entirely unrelated browser will show that message as well provided that the user agent string matches.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wladimir. BTW. Mozilla may wanna save non-authenticated user's data in user's browser.